# How to get the usage time (age of), Modal Number, software version of the iPhone using obj c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Anyone can tell me that how can I get the total life age (usage time), Modal Number, software version of the iPhone using obj c.
Also how can we check that iphone is jailbroken or not using objective C.

Thanks
MAS

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on this but you could give SystemConfiguration.framework (if it is even present on the iphone) a try.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the usage time, but you can get the device type and OS version from the [UIDevice class](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html):

```
NSLog(@"Device type: %@\niOS version: %@\n",
    [UIDevice currentDevice].model,
    [UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion);
// Might output this:
Device type: iPhone
iOS version: 2.0
```